# Domain regisration in Godaddy and Hosting in Plesk

Tags: cname-record, godaddy

I bought new domain in GOdaddy and host the site in plesk 9.2.2 . How to related these two.

While i adding the domain in plesk it automatically added 10 DNS records like A ,CNAME,MX.

but in godaddy it shows some name server . What about the next step. need to update A record

in Godaddy or Please guide me. Its  very urgent request

Answer (score 1):

All DNS records for the new domain will be created according to the default DNS zone template. You can modify it here: Server -> DNS settings. You can specify all of the needed DNS records for a particular domain's DNS zone too. However, I'm not familiar with Godaddy and I don't know exactly which records should be there.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few steps - jumping from A to Z without thinking of the steps inbetween.

First of all - what's doing your hosting, i.e where is your database, application, webserver etc. Your domain will have to point at that first.

Once that's in place you'll have to configure your system to use the new domain and/or IPs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you just bought your first domain, you need to configure it's A/CNAME/MX records on GoDaddy side. Just point all those records to the IP of the hosted machine.
For example, my configuration is similar to:

```
Type   Source         Destination

A      example.com    1.2.3.4
A    *.example.com    1.2.3.4

Type   Source         Priority

MX     example.com    10
```

This is very simple configuration to point ALL possible requests for your domain name to particular IP. Name servers is something you should not bother. If you purchased your domain from GoDaddy, they will provide you with their name servers, and there is no need to change them. The same is with e.g. Yahoo, and others.

Next step is configuration of your hosted server, which is out of this scope, and thus it is specific to your desired configuration.

Please note, updating DNS records takes some time. According to what I have read, it should take about 1 day to tell all the world that your domain is at specific IP address, but in practice that's about 2-3 hours.